# Connectivity between VMs of separate instance of Windows Azure

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have one VM in China Azure (https://portal.azure.cn/ ) (https://www.azure.cn ) (China Service) and another VM is in Hong Kong (Global service). I have made a connection between both the VMs using VNET but when I try to ping both the VMs then I get too many drops ( Time-out). 
How can I establish the connection between both the VMs which are in separate instance of Azure ? I want to make sure there is no packet drops and the connection between both the VMs should work smoothly without any drop.
Please help me out.

Thanks,
Vishwajeet.

Comment: You may refer the below considerations for Connecting Virtual Networks in Azure across Different Regions: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/vnet-to-vnet-connecting-virtual-networks-in-azure-across-different-regions/

Comment: I am trying to connect vms in separate azure instance not different region. China Azure instance is totally different from Global Azure instance.. it's not like firewall is blocking ICMP package. Sometimes I can ping other vm but sometimes I get packet drops.